# opening venv with crontab on python3 mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron, python-venv

I am using oh-my-zsh, python 3.6.1 on a mac. I would like to run a crontab to execute a python3 script.

One of my latest tries was this (none of the 20 different stackoverflow answers I found worked, so please don't shut this down as a duplicate:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
24 12 * * * root source env/latest-env/bin/activate && /usr/local/bin/python3 /path/to/file/data_transfer.py
```

The error is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'some_module'`, hence it is not activating my virtual_env, because that model exists in the latest virtual environment.
I get the same error when using `#!env/latest-env/bin/python` at the top of my script and running it.

I also tried the venv version instead:

```
activate_this = '/path/to/env/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

But this is for python 2, so the error is `NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined`, when I change it to exec, then I am getting `NameError: name 'env' is not defined`. But I know this is my path.

How can I activate my latest venv in a crontab to get my script running?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created a virtual environment, the environment is bound to the interpreter in its */bin* subdirectory. You should therefore find that a crontab entry such as

```
24 12 * * * root /path/to/env/latest-env/bin/python /path/to/file/data_transfer.py
```

will do everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar challenge and discovered a solution that effectively sets environment variables for each cron job, which is crucial as each cron job starts in a fresh environment, and each cronjob may need different variables. I created a `.sh` script to be executed by cron, setting up the necessary environment before running the Python script. Here's an example script:

```bash
#!/bin/zsh
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin # set your paths.
# set any other env variable, or execute any other action to init the cron env.
/Users/me/.pyenv/shims/python /Users/me/my-script.py
```

Setup instructions:

- Set `PATH` using the output from `echo $PATH` in your terminal.
- Use the absolute path of the Python executable, found via `which python`.
- Provide the absolute path to your Python script.

Ensure this script is executable with `chmod +x my-cron.sh`.

Your Python script doesn't need any special headers or metadata, for instance:

```py
import subprocess
import json
# ... rest of the python script.
```

Manage Python versions and dependencies with `pyenv shims`, setting the global Python version using `pyenv global 3.9.18 3.11.5`. Other python management solutions will work too.

To add this to your crontab:

1. Open crontab with `crontab -e` in terminal.
2. Define your cron job and script path like this: `*/1 * * * * /Users/me/my-cron.sh`. (this example will run every minute)
3. To save and exit, press `ESC`, type `:wq` (**w**rite, **q**uit), and then press `Enter`. You will see a confirmation message: "crontab: installing new crontab".

This approach ensures that your Python script runs with the correct environment and dependencies, as managed by `pyenv`.